# the remote user remains when the component is unmounted

Tags: twilio

when unmounting my twilio class, the remote user remains in the array as a result of which I have a duplicate video of the remote user

I tried directly clearing the array of participants when unmounting the class, but it didn’t give any result

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just an FYI, Twilio Programmable Video is no longer supported, and will end of life on December 5th, 2024. The [official migration path](https://www.twilio.com/en-us/changelog/programmable-video-eol-notice) is to migrate to [Zoom Video SDK](https://developers.zoom.us/docs/video-sdk/twilio/). We are happy to support your use case.